# use WHERE CLAUSE for search data from A date until B date

Tags: php, mysql, date, where-clause

lets say i have two drop down list and one button on my search page:

```
From
<select id="1stdate">
Until
<select id="2nddate">
<input type="button" id="search">
```

i want to search data from `1stdate` until `2nddate`, how to use WHERE CLAUSE for this case? for ex. i want to search data "from 09-2010 until 11-2010".
this my query:

```
SELECT CONCAT( YEAR(Inspection_datetime ),'-',LPAD(MONTH(Inspection_datetime),2,'0'))
FROM `inspection_report`
GROUP BY  CONCAT( MONTH(Inspection_datetime ),YEAR(Inspection_datetime))
ORDER BY  CONCAT( MONTH(Inspection_datetime ),YEAR(Inspection_datetime))  DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually did something like this:

```
<?php

list($m1, $y1) = explode($_1stdate);
list($m2, $y2) = explode($_2nddate);

$date1 = "$y1-$m1-01";
$date2 = "$y2-$m2-" . date("t", mktime(0,0,0,$m2, 1, $y2));

$sql = "SELECT *
FROM `inspection_report`
WHERE DATE(Inspection_datetime) BETWEEN '$date1' AND '$date2'";
```

Please note: for simplicity's sake, I don't add form validations.

Answer (score 0):

this is what you need:

```
WHERE Inspection_datetime BETWEEN $1stdate AND $2nddate
```

so it will result in

```
SELECT CONCAT( YEAR(Inspection_datetime ),'-',LPAD(MONTH(Inspection_datetime),2,'0'))
FROM `inspection_report` WHERE Inspection_datetime BETWEEN $1stdate AND $2nddate
GROUP BY  CONCAT( MONTH(Inspection_datetime ),YEAR(Inspection_datetime))
ORDER BY  CONCAT( MONTH(Inspection_datetime ),YEAR(Inspection_datetime))  DESC
```

Comment: owh..i guest i couldn't use Inspection_datetime directly.could i use a concat like '".$1stDate."'?

Comment: why not? what's the problem with that?

Comment: shure you could but writing string slike "This is a string with the value of a var $var in it" is prefectly right because a "" string will be interpreted differently than a '' string and $var will be evaluated